# Proper capitalization of titles

Tags: capitalization

Which is correct, re capitalization of the word "mayor"?

San Francisco Mayor John Doe ...

San Francisco mayor John Doe ...

Comment: And what about "the crack-smoking mayor of Toronto...?"

Answer (score 1):

US English may vary from my UK usage, but here's the general consensus according to [this page that collects and summarises several style guides](http://www.editors.co.uk/articles/2/capital-offence).

When the word is used as a component of someone's proper name, or in a full job title, capitalise.  "Mayor Smith plans to replace Main Street with a monorail."  "Dick Whittington has been elected Mayor of London."

For other uses of the word, and derivatives of it (like mayoral), don't capitalise.  "What is he the mayor of, anyway?" "I made myself a mayoral sash out of an old label."

For example, the Guardian style guide quoted says this:

> cap up [capitalise] titles, but not job description, eg President Barack Obama (but the US president, Barack Obama, and Obama on subsequent mention); the Duke of Westminster (the duke at second mention); the Queen, but the pope.

Other than the Queen, who is getting special treatment there for probably long-established cultural reasons, the others are all consistent.