# Please tell me if president should be capitalized here

Tags: capitalization

So when I was promoted to president of the club, I took the opportunity to introduce new events.

From my experience as president of Pre-med Club, I can confidently say that leadership is about encouraging constructive interpersonal interactions between people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding U.S. President capitalization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/understanding-u-s-president-capitalization) (though probably better addressed at [proper capitalization of titles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162939/proper-capitalization-of-titles/163070#163070)).

Answer (score 1):

When mentioning a role in general, it’s often left lowercase:

> A president is the head of affairs.
>
> A governor’s responsibility is to govern.
>
> He served on a panel of judges.
>
> The administrators of the school are set to meet tomorrow.

When referring to a specific role or using it as an honorific or form of address, it’s capitalised:

> Abraham Lincoln was the President of the United States.
>
> I visited Governor Smith and Mayor Lee last week.
>
> He served on the Panel of Judges.
>
> That’s a very good idea, Administrator Paulsen.

In your examples, I would write:

> “…when I was promoted to **president of the club**…” (generic title)
>
> “From my experience as **President of Pre-med Club**…” (official title)